# KendoUI Editor Template Issue With KendoUI Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I have a KendoUI Grid that is outputting some Foreign Key dropdowns and other fields like dates and for some reason some random text/characters are being added before and after the control is rendered.  In this block below, `<$Bw$> <$Bx$>` is being output to the browser as text before the select list is rendered followed by `<$By$>`.

```
<td role="gridcell" data-container-for="StateProvinceId">&lt;$Bw$&gt;
<!--$Bw$-->&lt;$Bx$&gt;<span style="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="StateProvinceId_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false"><span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"><span unselectable="on" class="k-input">&nbsp;</span><span unselectable="on" class="k-select"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span></span></span><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field StateProvinceId must be a number." data-val-required="The StateProvinceId field is required." id="StateProvinceId" name="StateProvinceId" type="text" value="0" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;" data-bind="value:StateProvinceId" class="valid"></span><script>
    jQuery(function(){jQuery("#StateProvinceId").kendoDropDownList({"dataSource":[],"dataTextField":"Text","dataValueField":"Value"});});
</script><!--$Bx$-->&lt;$By$&gt;
<!--$By$--><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="StateProvinceId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></td>
```

The FK editor template is simply the default.

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@model object
           
@(
 Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)        
        .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])
)
```

This is happening with all of the fields being rendered that have a KendoUI editor template.

[image: Screenshot of error]

#### Code for Grid

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model Data.DataModels.Person

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Data.ViewModels.LicenseVM>()
    .Name("LicensesGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.StateProvinceId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["StateProvinces"], "StateProvinceId", "Name")
            .Title("State");
        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.LicenseTypeId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["LicenseTypes"], "LicenseTypeId", "Name")
            .Title("Type");
        columns.Bound(p => p.LicenseNumber).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ExpirationDate).Width(150);
        columns.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Edit(); // The "edit" command will edit and update data items
            commands.Destroy(); // The "destroy" command removes data items
        }).Title("").Width(200);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolBar =>
        {
            toolBar.Create().Text("Add License");
        })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.PersonLicenseId);
            model.Field(p => p.PersonId).Editable(false).DefaultValue(@Model.PersonId);
        })
        .Read(read => read.Action("_GetLicenses", "Person", new { PersonId = Model.PersonId }))
        .Create(create => create.Action("_AddLicense", "Person"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("_EditLicense", "Person"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("_DeleteLicense", "Person"))
    )
)

<script type="text/javascript">
    function errorHandler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            alert(message);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any way you could provide a working jsBin/jsFiddle example that demonstrates the problem? I know you're using the .NET server helpers, so it may be a bit harder, but a repo demo of your scenario would be a big help for debugging (even if just to understand your configuration)!

Comment: @Todd Given the use of .NET I don't think I can replicate this that easily...  I'm open to some other ideas though, DM me through Twitter and perhaps we can open an email exchange on trouble shooting?

Comment: One likely problem is the format of your JSON data. If that has some unusual characters, it could be causing the rendering anomalies you see. Can you share the JSON you're trying to bind to your grid?

Comment: Hopefully the image above is worth a thousand words.  When this solution is deployed on Azure, I do not see these characters so it is only happening via localhost/development.

Comment: This is a very strange issue. Please try disabling the AntiXSS library (from web.config). Another problem may be corrupted editor templates (For whatever reason). It is virtually impossible to search for <!--$Bx$--> with google :)

Comment: I'm not seeing any AntiXSS even enabled in the web.config...

Comment: @RSolberg can you show your code how you bind `Forenkey` in grid.

Comment: @RSolberg @Todd I have the same problem. The problem only occurs when `debug="true"` is set in `web.config`

Comment: Please see my answer. It's likely BrowserLink causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely markup added by BrowserLink. I recommend you disable it for this scenario.

http://www.poconosystems.com/software-development/how-to-disable-browser-link-in-visual-studio-2013/